# A simple/more elegant way of stopping the code when a variable is nil?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I'm using the following code to scrap sections in a site:

```
class Parser
  def self.parse(html)
    @data = Nokogiri.HTML(open(html))
    merged_hashes = {}

    array_of_hashes = [
      parse_department,
      parse_super_saver,
      parse_new_arrivals,
      parse_out_of_stock,
      parse_categories,
      parse_results,
      parse_category
    ]
    array_of_hashes.inject(merged_hashes,:update)

    return merged_hashes
  end

  .
  .
  .

  def self.parse_results
    results = @data.css('#refinements ul').first
    unless results
      @results_hash = {}
      return @results_hash
    end

    if results.css('li:nth-child(1) a span').text == "Pet Supplies"
      @results_hash = {}
      @results_hash[:results] ||= {}
      @results_hash[:results] = @data.at_css('#resultCount span').text[/(\S+) Results$/i, 1].delete(",").to_i
    else
      @results_hash = {}
    end

    return @results_hash
  end
```

As you can see in this part:

```
    results = @data.css('#refinements ul').first
    unless results
      @results_hash = {}
      return @results_hash
    end
```

I'm stopping the code if `results` is `nil`. The reason for that is that the code will break if the `.at_css` method below is applied to a nil value.

This happens because sometimes the html won't have CSS selector that the method is looking for.

That's why I want to stop the code there.

I have to repeat that in each method. Is there a simpler or more elegant way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just write

```
return {} if results.nil?
```

I do have some suggestions, though:

- Do you really need to set `@results_hash`? Because i think it should not be an instance variable at all. You're using a class method (`def self.parse_results`) anyway.
- Why do you need to nest the results in `@results_hash[:results]`? In my opinion, it would be sufficient to just fill `results_hash` directly. That way, you can initialize the `results_hash` variable *once* with an empty hash.
- The line `@results_hash[:results] ||= {}` is really superfluous, because you immediately overwrite that value in the next line, anyway.
- Ruby implicitly returns the value of the last expression, so you can drop the last `return`. Although one needs to get used to this notation, its use is widespread and generally considered “good style”

That said, i'd write the method this way:

```
def self.parse_results
  results_hash = {}

  results = @data.css('#refinements ul').first
  return results_hash if results.nil?

  if results.css('li:nth-child(1) a span').text == "Pet Supplies"
    results_hash = @data.at_css('#resultCount span')
                        .text[/(\S+) Results$/i, 1]
                        .delete(",")
                        .to_i
  end

  results_hash
end
```